# #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation in C Panel

Tags: mysql, set, global

i want do this 
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
and i have this problem 
1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
and I cant solve this problem pls help

Comment: Are you using phpMyAdmin?  What are you using to edit the dB/?

Comment: yes I use phpmyadmin ,i use this query SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

Comment: Are you logged in as root in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i reset MYSQL pswd in c panel and I logined

Comment: That doesn't answer my question -_-

Comment: To edit an existing user, simply click the pencil icon to the right of that user in the Users page. You can then edit their global- and database-specific privileges, change their password, or even copy those privileges to a new user.

Comment: You need to change permission with SUPER checked.

Comment: #Rafael it is doesnt work

Comment: You need to edit the user roots permissions in MySQL itself.  In other words you can't use phpMyAdmin anymore you broke it.  But you can fix it in MySQL.

Comment: http://kb.site5.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/sa_dbuser_1.png

Comment: Worst comes to worst you can use Remote MySQL to fix it.  Let me know if you get it with the picture I sent

Comment: http://imgur.com/ObtnQKw user have all of them

Comment: That is for user `montecha_yolchu` these are basic privileges  not super privileges like root has.  You need to log in as root.

Comment: I logined root 'montecha' user but montecha user no user list i cant edit it

Comment: My friend I am telling you that you need to log in simply as `root` in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: i dont know password :D

Comment: **MySQL's default root password is an empty string (no password is set).**  If that doesn't work try using the FTP login password.

Comment: Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Comment: Ok then try with FTP login password (the password you use to upload files).

Comment: #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: You cannot do this without contacting GoDaddy or whoever you use's support and asking them very nicely to create or edit an account with the privileges you want (SUPER Privileges)on the database you need them to be added to.

Comment: https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/354 check this

Comment: Awe that sucks man.  You can't do it.  Like I said, you probably just have to call them and ask one of their techs if they can run that command for you.

Comment: Try removing `GLOBAL` and see if you can do it

Comment: i try it but my problem not solved then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET group_concat_max_len = 1000000` and leave the word `GLOBAL` out and that will fix it. You must be a superuser to use `GLOBAL` in your script.